# How to realize csrf within django using paypal?

Tags: django, paypal, csrf

according to the tutorial https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/standard/ipn.html I try to implement Paypal to my webpage.

What I have so far:

views.py

```
def view_that_asks_for_money(request):
    c = {}
    # What you want the button to do.
    paypal_dict = {
        "business": settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
        "amount": "0.01",
        "item_name": "name of the item",
        "invoice": "unique-invoice-id",
        "notify_url": "xxx/nnnn" + reverse('paypal-ipn'),
        "return_url": "xxx/aaa",
        "cancel_return": "xxx/bbb",
        "custom": "Upgrade all users!",  # Custom command to correlate to some function later (optional)
    }

    # Create the instance.
    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
    c.update({"form":form})
    return render_to_response(app/payment.html",
                              c,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
    ipn_obj = sender
    print("hierkamwsan")
    if ipn_obj.payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED:
        # Undertake some action depending upon `ipn_obj`.
        if ipn_obj.custom == "Upgrade all users!":
            print("upgradedUser")
            #Users.objects.update(paid=True)
    else:
        print("UwerNotValid")

valid_ipn_received.connect(show_me_the_money)
```

urls.py (within app):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('views',
    url(r'money$', 'view_that_asks_for_money', name='view_that_asks_for_money'),#paypal
    url(r'nnnn$', 'show_me_the_money', name='show_me_the_money')#supposed to be the notify_url
)
```

urls.py (general in django-cms):

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),
    ) + staticfiles_urlpatterns() + urlpatterns  # NOQA
```

payment.html

```
<{% extends 'base.html' %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% block content %}
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Paypal-Payment</title>   
    </head>
    <body>h1>Show me the money!</h1>
<!-- writes out the form tag automatically -->
{{ form.render }}
{% csrf_token %}
</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

When calling the views.py/payment.html it is possible to pay in the paypal-sandbox. When directed back to my page I get an django-debugger error:

```
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Help

Reason given for failure:

CSRF token missing or incorrect.


In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:

    Your browser is accepting cookies.
    The view function uses RequestContext for the template, instead of Context.
    In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
    If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.

You're seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.

You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.
```

Can anybody tell me:

- how to implement the csrf-token correctly
- if handling the response of paypal with the notify_url is implemented properly. As I suppose the calling "valid_ipn_received.connect(show_me_the_money)" within views is wrong. But where to do it?

EDIT (I added the source of the payment.html form as it is delivered to the browser):

```
<body>h1>Show me the money!</h1>
<!-- writes out the form tag automatically -->
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input id="id_business" name="business" type="hidden" value="mymail@mymail.com" /><input id="id_amount" name="amount" type="hidden" value="0.01" /><input id="id_item_name" name="item_name" type="hidden" value="name of the item" /><input id="id_notify_url" name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="http://xxxxx.ngrok.com/en/mypage/" /><input id="id_cancel_return" name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="http://xxxxx.ngrok.com/en/accounts/login/" /><input id="id_return_url" name="return" type="hidden" value="http://xxxxx.ngrok.com/de/accounts/login/" /><input id="id_custom" name="custom" type="hidden" value="Upgrade all users!" /><input id="id_invoice" name="invoice" type="hidden" value="unique-invoice-id29" /><input id="id_cmd" name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick" /><input id="id_charset" name="charset" type="hidden" value="utf-8" /><input id="id_currency_code" name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" /><input id="id_no_shipping" name="no_shipping" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Buy it Now" />
</form>
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='5VDa6VWHZFAD6thEsOIwKxhlWPOlOD62' />
</body>
```

I am looking forward to your help!
Marina

Comment: It doesn't look like the CSRF token is being rendered inside of the form. If you load the page and look at the source, is the token inside of the form tags or outside?

Comment: I edited my post and added the source as it is delivered to the browser. How can I get the csrf-token inside of the form?

Answer (score 0):

I am still struggling. Found the following in the templates of django-paypal. This is the render command for the default button I get.

```
    def render(self):
        return mark_safe(u"""<form action="%s" method="post">
    %s 
    <input type="image" src="%s" border="0" name="submit" alt="Buy it Now" />
</form>""" % (self.get_endpoint(), self.as_p(), self.get_image()))
```

Now I am wondering if it is possible to integrate the csrf_token somewhere whithin this render definition. 
Is it? And where do I have to add it? Would this really be the solution? Or is there something more clever and elegant?